# Symfony 5 custom reusable bundle installation using flex - how to test and run a private recipe server

Tags: symfony, symfony-flex

I have created a test reusable Symfony 5 bundle and have written a Flex recipe to automatically install and configure it within any project which is private.

My problem is, I have no idea how to run and test this.  I cannot find any clear complete instructions anywhere.  The official documentation does not specify how this would be done and only specifies how to create the manifest.json file.

https://github.com/symfony/recipes

I found the following info which specifies uploading the recipe to a private repository on GitHub and then activating Symfony Recipe Server for the repository which I have done.

https://blog.mayflower.de/6851-symfony-4-flex-private-recipes.html

but then what?

Answer (score 2):

If understood this correctly, you want to add custom domain from where recipe would be downloaded and installed. Check this project:

Github https://github.com/moay/server-for-symfony-flex

Docs https://server-for-symfony-flex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Eventually you get to the point where you add custom endpoint from where to download the recipe like this:

> Using the server in your Symfony project is as easy
> as adding the proper endpoint to your composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "symfony": {
        "endpoint": "https://your.domain.com"
    }
}
```

I apologize if this is not in the desired format of an answer.